# Google Maps: unrecognized selector sent to instance error:

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I've looked at a couple of other SO post on this and checked what they suggested but I am still getting a crash when I try to instantiate a Google Map.

In my build settings I have Other Linker Flags for debug and release set to -Objc

In my viewcontroller where the map will be instantiated I am importing the Google Maps framework and have this code:

```
GMSCameraPosition* cameraPosition = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:self.currentLocation.latitude
                                                                    longitude:self.currentLocation.longitude
                                                                         zoom:10];

    self.myMapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:cameraPosition];
    self.view = self.myMapView;
```

And I am getting this debugger output on the crash:

-[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7cdf6680

Other Linker Flag seems to be the main culprit for this crash but is there something else that could cause it?

Edit:Should note this crashes with CGRectZero or if I use self.view.bounds for the rect.

Edit: Switching -Objc to -ObjC created a linker error:

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: do u have the method animateToCameraPosition: ?

Comment: Mr. T - it's my understanding that this method is part of the Google map framework, when you pass a camera position to the GMSMapView it calls this method.

Vive: Yes.

Comment: the crash is saying that u r sending something which u r not supposed to!!!! How u r calling this method ?

Comment: I am not calling or sending anything, the GMS Framework is. When you instantiate a Google Map View you pass it the rect you want the map view to appear in and a GMSCamera object (latitude and longitude and zoom level). When the map view receives this it then calls the method animateToCameraPosition from within it's m files. I do not have access to this method and something is preventing the GMSMapView from instantiating properly, which is why it cannot recognize the selector. I am trying to figure out what I need to do to instantiate it properly.

Comment: try setting -ObjC instead of -Objc

Comment: switching to -ObjC game me a linker error.

Comment: What is the error? are you using Parse SDK?

Comment: -Objc is not valid flag -ObjC is. You need to use -ObjC.

Comment: I know, I didn't originally developed the app but whoever did put -Objc in instead of -ObjC, but changing it to -ObjC generates a linker error (see edit in OP)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96042/discussion-between-pruitigoe-and-pratyusha-terli).

Comment: did you add GMSMapViewDelegate enclosed in <> for class interface?

Comment: Yes. I did try self.myMapView.delegate = self; before posting here but that had no affect.

Answer (score -1):

Try opening the project.xcworkspcae, and run it again.